# Spring MVC - Change in .Exe file to .txt makes browser change content type

Tags: security, spring-mvc, file-upload

In my Spring MVC 3.0 based application I am trying to test the file upload functionality with some validations. 
In one validation I changed .exe(executable) file to .txt , and expecting that exe file shouldn't be uploaded in the system.But it gets uploaded.

I am checking content type of file but in this case once file extension is changed it's content types also gets changed from "application/octet-stream" to "text/plain".

I am testing on Firefox and Google Chrome. And At Controller level Uploaded file is being read using MultipartFile.

Is there any way by which I get the original content type of file in this case "application/octet-stream" ?

Answer (score 1):

When we change the extension of the file before uploading it ..It depends on Operating System weather the MIME type will change or not. Moreover, it is the responsibility of the browser to find out the Mime Type and set into the request header which is being read in the controller.

Comment: @Himani..Is there any setting by which we can ask browser to always send original MIME type ?

Comment: I was also trying the same validation on controller ..but did not find any alternative